# React, Apollo 2, GraphQL, Authentication system

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/507w9qxrrl

I don't understand:

1) **How to re-render() `Menu`** component after:

```
this.props.client.query({
  query: CURRENT_USER_QUERY,
  fetchPolicy: "network-only"
});
```

If I login() I expect my `Menu` component to re-render() itself. But nothing. If I click on the Home link it re-render(). I suspect because I'm using this to render it:

```
<Route component={Menu} />
```

for embrace it in react-router props. Is it wrong?

2) **How to prevent `Menu` component to query if not authenticated** (eg: there isn't a token in localStorage); I'm using in `Menu` component this code:

```
export default graphql(CURRENT_USER_QUERY)(Menu);
```

3) **Is this the right way to go?**

Comment: Why would you want the component to rerender? It wont because it is not using the graphql HoC, which uses client.watchQuery internally. Yuu are using client.query once to get some data. Changes that mutate that piece of data will not trigger rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider moving `CURRENT_USER_QUERY` into your App.jsx component. It would be similar to what I have below.

My`AppContainer` is my parent component. It checks if the user is logged in. It can then take the query result and passes the user/role down to the child components (i.e. Menu.jsx in your case). This way you can check if a user is logged in and subsequently change which components to show them

```js
const loggedInUser = gql`
  query loggedInUser{
    user {
      id
      role
    }
  }`


export default graphql(loggedInUser, { options: {fetchPolicy: 'network-only' }})(AppContainer)
```

Here's a fuller example of AppContainer.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppNav from 'AppNav';
import ExampleContainer from 'ExampleContainer';
import ExampleContainerTwo from 'ExampleContainerTwo';
import LoginPage from 'LoginPage';

const AppContainer = ({ data }) => {
  if (data.loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  //checks if user is logged in
  if (data.user) {
    return (
      <div id="app-container">
        <AppNav adminUser={data.user.role === 'ADMIN' ? true : false} />
        <div className="content">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/app/" component={ExampleContainer} />
            <Route path="/app/example-two" component={ExampleContainerTwo} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return <LoginPage handleUserLoggedIn={() => data.refetch()} />
}

const loggedInUser = gql`
      query loggedInUser{
        user {
          id
          role
        }
      }`

export default graphql(loggedInUser, { options: {fetchPolicy: 'network-only' }})(AppContainer)
```